# Ошибка во время установки Squid Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, virtualbox, squid

Во время сборки Squid (примерно через минут 30) вылезает ошибка, сервер на виртуальной машине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. если, как написано в заголовке, вы хотите установить программу squid, то зачем вы её компилируете вместо того, чтобы просто установить пакет, содержащий уже скомпилированную программу?

Comment: Не настроил буфер обмена с virualbox, и я хочу добавить ssl поэтому собираю